# Extract Information from Webpage onto Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importxml

I've been trying to grab some data from this webpage: https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/BZUN. I want to import the follower count (under the add to portfolio button) into a cell on google sheets. For example, the data I'd try to import under this page would be the (**22,201** followers).

I think that I need to use `=importXML` with this. However, it's not working. From the research that I've done, it's because that value isn't static and comes from another source.

I believe that the remedy to my problem is do use Regex Extract, but I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> From the research that I've done, it's because that value isn't static and comes from another source

You are not wrong there. after disabling JavaScript you can observe that followers count case to exist, and therefore not even regex will help.

Answer (score 0):

[REGEXTRACT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) isn't the replacement of IMPORTXML. It uses a regular expression to extract text from a value.

If the content is dynamic I don't think that it's possible to use Google Sheets to get that content, instead you will have to use a tool similar or based on a web browser that executes the client side code to generate the dynamic content.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response!